# Redirect users to content outside Angular but as a subpath of the application

Tags: angular, apache, redirect, subdomain

I currently have a main website, in Angular, and a few landing pages as subdomains, in pure HTML/JS.
I was requested that instead of `lp.website.com`, the urls should now be `website.com/lp`.

Considering that the folders for all of the pages and the angular app are on the same server under Apache, how could I redirect the user to the appropriate content, but keeping the `website.com/lp` URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file you can create an alias. This way you can keep the current structure completely intact, until you can phase out the subdomain landing pages.

```
RewriteEngine on

#Make sure we only rewrite for domains example.com and www.example.com
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$

# If the request URI is either /lp or /lp/ do an internal redirect
# (The leading slash of the request URI is stripped before matching)
RewriteRule ^lp/?$ https://lp.example.com/
```

The RewriteRule does the following:

The user requests `https://example.com/lp/`, but after rewriting the server 'thinks' the user requested `https://lp.example.com/`

Here is an example the other way around.

```
# Make sure we only rewrite for the lp.example.com domain
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^lp.example.com$
# Rewrite all root requests to https://example.com/lp/
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://example.com/lp/
```

The server receives a request for `https://lp.example.com`. The rewrite condition ensures the rewrite only happens for lp.example.com. The RewriteRule does an internal redirect to `http://example.com/lp/`

More information https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I don't know much about the .htaccess syntax, but could you elaborate a bit more on what the last line does, please? As of today, all my files are in the directory for the subdomain URL. What I need is that, regardless of when the user types in the subdomain or the subpath URL they are shown the same content.